# Blank field when inserting PHP current session_id into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, sessionid

I'm trying to insert the session_id along with other values into a database table when the user signs up, however the session_id field always ends up blank in the database, which is very weird, because I'm starting the session correctly with session_start(), I've even used var_dump at the session_id and the string that I'm using to execute the query in order to see if the session id is in there, and it is. Another funny thing is that when I place any other string instead of the result generated from session_id() it is registered in the database, unless the string I'm trying to use is the result taken from the var_dump() on session_id(), which is very strange, because if I go to another browser and generate a different session id, copy and paste it there, it works, also if I use the same SQL statement directly into SQL command prompt or phpMyAdmin using the session_id() that I can't insert with PHP, it works perfectly. I don't know why but it's not allowing me to insert the id of the current session via mysql_query. My code is the following:

```
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup_email']);
 $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup_password']));
 $origPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup_password']);
 $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
 $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
 $mobile_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile_phone']);
 $sessionID = session_id();
 $fullName = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name." ".$last_name);
 var_dump($sessionID);

 //Inserting user info
 $q_user = "INSERT INTO
                minders (

                            name,
                            phone,
                            ssid,
                            insert_datetime,
                            status,
                            email,
                            password,
                            is_minder,
                            login_allowed
                        )
            VALUES
                        (

                            '{$fullName}',
                            '{$mobile_phone}',
                            '{$sessionID}',
                            now(),
                            'deactivated',
                            '{$email}',
                            '{$password}',
                            0,
                            1
                        )";

 var_dump($q_user);

 $r_user = mysql_query($q_user) or die(mysql_error());
```

I hope someone can help me with that. Thanks very much!
Note: I know mysql_query is deprecated but isn't feasible for me to change it.

Comment: Why would you want to store the users session ID?  this is a temporary string.

Comment: That's isn't really a choice for me, I'm working on someone else's code, and the session id is being used to identify the currently logged user, I'm creating this new signup page, and after the signup the user has to be logged in. Every time the user logs out this field is cleaned and every time he logs in it's filled again.

Comment: do you have session_start(); at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes, I have it on the top.

Comment: when you var dump the sql query, have you tried copying and pasting that directly into sql and see if you get any errors?  Maybe the field is not setup to handle the string

Comment: and does that show the session_id?

Comment: directly into sql it is inserted perfectly, the session is shown in there.

Comment: My pin number has been compromised, but it's not feasible for me to change it.

Comment: I've just tried this using PDO, same thing.. any ideas?